# Run R Shiny App From OSX Terminal

Tags: r, macos, terminal, shiny, rscript

I've installed the below R app and managed to get it up and running absolutely fine.

https://github.com/kadekillary/ngram-shiny-app

I want to create a command file which will execute the app and have tried several solutions but no luck so far.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you consider putting into a docker container? https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/shiny/

Comment: What exactly did you try and how exactly did they not work?

Comment: I tried navigating to the project folder, running r, opening the shiny library then running the app - a process which works fine if done manually - not sure why this doesn't work when I package those commands in sequence inside a command file.

Answer (score 2):

You can run R in the working directory the following way:

```
 R < app.R  --no-save
```

It should open something like "Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6978"

Open this address in your browser.

Comment: Thanks! This achieves what I want. Is there an easy way to get it to auto open the URL with chrome and close terminal at the same time? Thanks so much

Comment: You can use "crontab -e" to edit time for autorunning